# How to store and retrieve video files and image files in hbase table

Tags: hbase

I have searched in documentation ,but there is no information about storing video file in hbase.I want implement in my project

Comment: for videos also do we  need to take as byte[] only?.I need sample code for inserting videos in hbase.

Comment: while storing 1gb of video file ,out of memory error is coming

Comment: Please dont use HBase to store 1GB of video file. Thats not a good use case for HBase.
If your file is bigger than few(0-10) MB's then dont store it in HBase.

Answer (score 2):

Please dont use HBase to store 1GB of video file. Thats not a good use case for HBase.
 
If your file is bigger than few(0-10) MB's then dont store it in HBase.