# How to store pdf/images to HBase Table

Tags: java, hadoop, pdf, hbase, blob

I am new to HBase. Below is what i am trying to achieve:
1. How to convert .pdf or .png to hbase readable format?
2. How to import these files in hbase table? (store metadata in one cf and object in another cf)

Can anyone share example on this? Any other suggestions are helpful.

Comment: just convert them to bytes using ByteArrayOutputStream or whatever, and save them as any other object

Comment: check my answer. there are many ways to do that.

Answer (score 0):

For an image See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41187269/647053). For PDF also this will work since we are trying  to store in most primitive way that is byte array. Suggest you to use [Serialization Utils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/SerializationUtils.html) for pdf as described in my example in the answer.

OR

Use Apache Commons IO `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File file)` which return data of type `byte[]`.

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131116/pdf-to-byte-array-and-vice-versa)